# How to remove generated files when running "ant release"

Tags: android, ant, build.xml

When running:

```
ant release
```

with my Android project, I get a ton of auto generated files.  For example:

```
MyApp-release-unaligned.apk 
MyApp-release-unsigned.apk  
MyApp-release-unsigned.apk.d    
MyApp-release.apk       
MyApp.ap_           
MyApp.ap_.d
build.prop
classes
classes.dex
classes.dex.d
res
```

I don't want all these files.  Basically all I need is the signed .apk. So I tried:

```
<target name="-post-compile">
    <!-- Clean up files that we don't want -->
    <delete dir="{$out.dir}res"/>
    <delete dir="{$out.dir}classes"/>
    <delete file="{$out.dir}${app.name}-release-unaligned.apk"/>
    <delete file="{$out.dir}${app.name}-release-unsigned.apk"/>
    <delete file="{$out.dir}${app.name}-release-unsigned.apk.d"/>
    <delete file="{$out.dir}${app.name}.ap_"/>
    <delete file="{$out.dir}${app.name}.ap_d"/>
    <delete file="{$out.dir}build.prop"/>
    <delete file="{$out.dir}classes.dex"/>
    <delete file="{$out.dir}classes.dex.d"/>
</target>
```

Evidently these files are generated after -post-compile is called.  Is there an easy way to adjust the build.xml to remove all but the signed apk?  My output directory is directed to a server and I would like to keep things simple there so that others don't pull the wrong file.  If there is no easy way to remove these files, I'll build a server-side script to do it but I would prefer to keep everything in the build.xml if possible.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add the target of removing the files as last line of the release command, however, I assume you don't create your own release target as most Android developers. Then another alternative will be to expose your target as say `<target name="remove-files">` and run the ant release like `ant release,remove-files`.

However, I just wonder why are those files such a bug burden?

Comment: Worked perfectly.  Thanks.  It's not that space is an issue I just don't want others getting confused by the other files that are on the server.  In addition, you have to add the target before the import at the end of the file. The command is 'ant release remove-files' without a comma.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe little bit late, but there's easier solution than accepted answer (not sure if it was valid at the time question has been asked).
There's `deleteonexit` attribute for [delete](https://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/delete.html) task which:

> Indicates whether to use File#deleteOnExit() if there is a failure to
>   delete a file, this causes the jvm to attempt to delete the file when
>   the jvm process is terminating. Since Ant 1.6.2

So, in `custom_rules.xml` it's possible to have something like that:

```
<target name="release" depends="clean, clean-out-release">
    <echo message="${basedir}"/>

    ...

    <!-- remove extra files from out project -->
    <delete deleteonexit="true">
        ...
        <!-- remove -unassigned, -unaligned files -->
        <fileset dir="./out" includes="*-unaligned.apk" />
        <fileset dir="./out" includes="*-unsigned.apk" />
    </delete>
</target>
```

Answer (score 1):

While the other approach (xml) is fine too. I just wanted to share our approach.
We are using Windows and we have a batch file that is called **build.bat**.
After the batch file have finished calling commands for **ant building**, etc
We have this on our last lines of the build.bat

```
SET "APK_TMP3=%DIR_APP%\platforms\android\ant-build\%APP_PACKAGEID%.classes.dex"
IF EXIST "%APK_TMP3%" (
    del "%APK_TMP3%"
)
```

The files we delete are *-unaligned.apk, unsigned.apk, classes.dex, .ap_ files